# Jinja2 template in Python 3 renders bytes with "b" prefix and quotes

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I'm upgrading a Flask app from `python2` to `python3`,

`Jinja2` now renders bytes with trailing b and single quotes, e.g. `b'a123'` while I need them rendered as `a123`.

This happens with all urlsafe strings which came as string [not `unicode`] in python2 and were rendered as needed. Now they are bytes

I would like to avoid checking type every time and adding `.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem. Maybe it has been solved for you since the quetion has been past so long time.

In my problem, I open the file with 'rb' mode, and `read()` method for file handler will return `<type 'bytes'>`, so jinja2 `Template.render()` will also return a string wrapper of string. (Just something you call it bytes with prefix 'b' and quotes)

```py
with open("file.txt", "rb") as f:
    text = f.read()
    # type(text) -> <class 'bytes'>
    template = Template(f.read())
    template.render(kwargs)
```

After I modify the open mode with 'r', this time everything works as expected.

```py
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()
    # type(text) -> <class 'str'>
    template = Template(text)
    template.render(kwargs)
```

So the problem is the type of real parameter in Template constructor function.

Comment: In my opinion, this is so weird for Template class in jinja2. Maybe there are some other sceneries that I do not understand for this mode.

Comment: Hello, I have no template file reading in my code: `flask` takes care of it in `render_template`

Comment: Hi, at this time maybe you need to check the real parameter for constructing Template instance or something other like this. If you put  <class 'bytes'> type you get wrong result. If you put <class 'str'> type, everything works fine.